# What's the best way to customize / add pages to the admin generator?

Tags: symfony1, symfony-1.4, admin-generator

I'm using Symfony 1.4 and Doctrine.

My application's backend was built using Symfony's admin generator.
It works great when I want to display basic stuff.

But tehre's not a lot of documentation on how to enhance it and add new pages.

Let's take an example:
I want to list published items on one page and to-be-published items on another one. I've used several ways to that in my application but can't figure out what the best way is:

- playing with filters and then modify templates depending on where you are?
- creating another module calling a different `table_method`?
- some other technique I don't know about?

What's the best practice here?
How do you guys usually do to customize your admin?

Comment: Just checking: do you know you can simply extend your generated actions.class.php and templates/ directory with your own pages as with a normal symfony module? This is the easiest way to add pages, although you may need to pinch a little layout HTML from a generated template to keep the style consistent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shameless self-promotion here.  I wrote up a [blog post](http://www.whiteoctober.co.uk/blog/2010/03/23/symfony-admin-generator-theming/) this week on customising the admin generator - one of the things I did was to add new pages etc into the generator.  The way I did it is probably a bit hardcore, but it works nicely :-)

The best place to start looking is the auto-generated actions class for your module and extending it in your `app/module/actions/actions.class.php` file.  In particular, the index action which sets up the ORM pager.  You should be able to use any query from your ORM to supply your ORM pager with data - in cases where I've needed to alter it, I use a Doctrine query generated in the same way as normal to pass to the pager.  This means that I can customise what fields are displayed, including ones from other tables joined in etc in a single query.  This is your 'table method' mentioned above.

Filters will work just as well - it depends on your use case and whether filters are appropriate, particularly for display.  If you want a `/showpublisheditems page`, then I'd go with a new action and the new query for the pager.  If you want on-the-fly customisation, then go with the filter option.

The filter docs I thought were a bit lacking in places too - quick tip, they look for a `addYourColumnNameColumnQuery()` method in your top-level filter class (lib/filter/...) which takes a query passed in and uses eg `addWhere("x.column_name = ?", $foo)` to the query passed in.

Bleh :-) sorry, that was a bit of a brain dump, but hopefully it helps! :-)